# HotTowel.Angular.Breeze for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2015, breeze, nuget-package, hottowel

I hope you can help me.

I am busy following the John Papa course - *Building apps with angular and breeze* -
 (http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/build-apps-angular-breeze), but pretty early on in the course I am getting issues with installing HotTowel.Angular.Breeze via NuGet. It seems there is some incompatibility issue with to$q and to%24q.

I get the following error:  'C:\Users\Admin.nuget\packages\HotTowel.Angular.Breeze\2.3.3\content\scripts\breeze.to%24q.shim.js'.

I am using Visual Studio 2015, and the only real solution I found was to move to VS 2013. But I am certain there must be a better solution or workaround.

I really appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution:**

I downloaded the source packages contained in the source files of the specific project on GitHub.

I then set a new Package Source in VS2015 pointing to the downloaded compatible packages, and installed it via that location.